# How to add a sidebar to archive page

Tags: wordpress, archive, sidebar

I would like add a sidebar to my archive page by code. The following codes were added into archive template. Sidebar was added successfully. However, the sidebar repeats post by post.

Please help me check the codes below.

```
<div class="row max_width">
        <div class="small-12 large-8 columns">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <figure class="post-gallery parallax">
            <div class="parallax_bg"
                        data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);"
                        data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('notio-single-3x'); ?>
            </div>
        </figure>
    <?php } ?>
            <header class="post-title">
                <?php get_template_part( 'inc/templates/postbits/post-meta' ); ?>
                <h3 itemprop="headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </header>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more-link"><?php esc_html_e( 'Read More', 'notio' ); ?></a>
            </div>
    <?php do_action( 'thb_PostMeta' ); ?>
        </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns sidebar">
                  <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ) ) : ?>
                  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ); ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
              </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
<div class="row max_width">
    <?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="small-12 large-8 columns">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <figure class="post-gallery parallax">
                    <div class="parallax_bg"
                    data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);"
                    data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('notio-single-3x'); ?>
                    </div>
                </figure>
            <?php } ?>
            <header class="post-title">
                <?php get_template_part( 'inc/templates/postbits/post-meta' ); ?>
                <h3 itemprop="headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </header>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more-link"><?php esc_html_e( 'Read More', 'notio' ); ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php do_action( 'thb_PostMeta' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns sidebar">
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ) ) : ?>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried these code. However, the archive page was not able to get access and turned into 504 gateway timeout.

Comment: In addition, my problem is that post can display normally one by one, but the sidebar repeat again and again.

Comment: I tried to put sidebar code and post code into while loop separately. But both led to 504.